# React Native metro server Fails, Command line disappears upon running program

Tags: react-native

i do this `npx react-native run-android` it shows the Command line metro server and then disappears immediately. 
Any idea why this happens?

I am getting this :

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.newawesomep/.MainActivity }
```

Yet, it just shows the command line interface and disappears

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Riddle. I managed to Downgrade from node 13.2.0 to 10.14.1
All works perfect without further hassle. Incase anyone comes across this Problem :)